# Simple loop reading from a text showing which line is reading

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix

I want to get which line is reading:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for ip in $(cat ip.txt);
    do
        date
    done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for better ways. Then you just need to keep a counter as you loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r ip
do
  ((c++))
  echo $c
  date
done < ip.txt
```

Comment: before my edit u was absolutly right, but i did an edid before notice me about ur answer, can u help me to improve my new problem?

Comment: Please reset your question and start a new one with this text. Thank you.

Comment: I started new one couse your answer was right before my edit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801249/bash-get-a-reverse-count-of-loop-in-output