# Bash - get a reverse count of loop in output

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I want to get a count of loop in reverse in output to know how many loop remaining I miss to finish.

```
#!/bin/bash
datenow=$(date +"%F")
logfile="table-"$datenow".log"
rm -f table.sql
mysql --login-path=myloginpath -h xhost -N -e \
"select count(*) from database.table a where a.field = 0;" | tee -a     $logfile
mysqldump --login-path=myloginpath-h xhost database table > table.sql
read -p "Insert Host Separated by comma ',' : " localcs
mysql --login-path=myloginpath -h xhost -N -e \
"select n.ipaddress from database.hosts n where n.hosts in ($localcs);"  > ip.txt
for ip in $(cat ip.txt);
do
mysql --login-path=myloginpath -h $ip "database" < "table.sql"
echo $ip  | tee -a $logfile && mysql --login-path=myloginpath -h $ip -N -e \
"select count(*) from database.table a where a.field = 0;" | tee -a $logfile
done
```

Something like this:

```
100
(mysql output)
99
(mysql output)
98
(mysql output)
.....
```

Comment: How much of this script is actually relevant to the question? Do you just want to loop through lines of `ip.txt` and print a decreasing number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to know how many lines are in the stream in advance.

```
num=$(wc -l < ip.txt)
while read -r ip; do
    # Do your work, use $num as needed

    # Then decrement num
    num=$((num-1))
done < ip.txt
```

By the way, this shows the recommended way of iterating over a file; don't use a `for` loop.

Comment: can also use `((num--))` as an alternative to `num=$((num-1))`

Comment: True; ignoring what the OP would actually put in the body of the loop, everything else in my answer is POSIX-compliant, so I decided to keep the decrement operation compliant as well. If there are already `bash`-only features being used, there's no harm in using `((num--))` instead.